# Can't make a common table expression with join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For some reason I can't make a CTE from the query:

```
SELECT LetterGrade, ES.Classification 
FROM Enrollment AS EN 
JOIN Students AS ES ON EN.StudentID = ES.StudentID
```

This statement:

```
WITH [DERIVED] AS
(
    SELECT LetterGrade, ES.Classification 
    FROM Enrollment AS EN 
    JOIN Students AS ES ON EN.StudentID = ES.StudentID
)
```

raises the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to use the `CTE`: `WITH [Derived] AS (.....)SELECT * FROM [Derived];`

Comment: In addition to Lamak's comment, if you have any statements before your CTE defintion, add a semicolon before `with`.

Comment: @JohnLBevan the error message would be different

Comment: The `CTE` is not complete without the `Select` statement following the declaration of the `CTE`. Hope this explains it well enough.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I mean, it could be complete if used with a `DELETE`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` too ;-)

Comment: @Lamak; agreed, sorry, tweaked my message to make it clear that it's in addition to yours.

Comment: @Lamak. Good point. Always learning! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches.

Option 1: Use an inner query:

```
select ...
from (SELECT LetterGrade, ES.Classification
      FROM Enrollment AS EN
      JOIN Students AS ES ON EN.StudentID = ES.StudentI) as Derived
where ...
```

This syntax is very portable. It works on all the major SQL databases.

Option 2: Use less often supported CTE syntax:

```
with Derived as (
    SELECT LetterGrade, ES.Classification
    FROM Enrollment AS EN
    JOIN Students AS ES ON EN.StudentID = ES.StudentI)
select ...
from Derived
where ...
```

This is much less portable (postgres for example supports it, mysql does not).
It can also be easier to read, and if the CTE is referred to multiple times can offer coding and performance benefits.

Comment: though it's true that mysql doesn't support CTEs, **they are** part of the ANSI SQL standard

Comment: Since I need to use the CTE approach for an assignment I'm constrained to use the second option. The way you wrote it (exactly the way I did) is still raising the same error of course

Comment: @EduardoA.FernándezDíaz then please write your whole query

Comment: @Lamak It has to be something really simple since that's my whole query and I can't see any reason for the error to be raised

Comment: @EduardoA.FernándezDíaz what's your whole query?, the one you posted in the question?. In that case I already commented what the error is

Comment: Thanks @Lamak , I just saw your first note

Comment: @EduardoA.FernándezDíaz I think your error is you don't have a select statement following your CTE. Try just adding `select * from Derived` after the CTE

Comment: That's was exactly the solution @Bohemian